# R shiny gauge graph disappear when I add new fluidRow in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I make a shiny app and I faced a trouble with the graph that disappears when I add a new `fluidRow`. Here is s small example

```
library(shinydashboard)
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Name')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
fluidRow(
    box(widht = 12, title = 'Group', textOutput('group_name'))
),
fluidRow(
    box(width = 4, title = 'Frim', textOutput('firm_name')),
    box(width = 4, title = 'INN', textOutput('firm_inn')),
    box(width = 4, title = 'Branch', textOutput('firm_branch'))
),
fluidRow(
    box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name1', plotlyOutput('firm_limits_utiliz'), solidHeader = TRUE),
    box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name2', plotlyOutput('firm_limits_remains'), solidHeader = TRUE),
    box(status = 'warning', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name3',  tableOutput('group_limits') , solidHeader = TRUE,
        style = "overflow-x: scroll;")
) )
ui <- dashboardPage(body = body, header = header, sidebar = sidebar, skin = 'blue')
server <- function(input, output) {

output$group_name <- renderText({'Shell'})

output$firm_name <- renderText({'Shell ltd'})

output$firm_inn <- renderText({'770565479'})

output$firm_branch <- renderText({'Oil and Gas'})

output$firm_limits_utiliz <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(
        domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
        value = 270,
        # title = list(text = "Speed"),
        type = "indicator",
        mode = "gauge+number",
        height = 197, width = 393) 
    fig <- fig %>%
        layout(margin = list(l=20,r=30))
    
    fig
})


output$group_limit_utiliz <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(
        domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
        value = 270,
        # title = list(text = "Speed"),
        type = "indicator",
        mode = "gauge+number",
        height = 197, width = 393) 
    fig <- fig %>%
        layout(margin = list(l=20,r=30))
    
    fig
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I run this code everything goes well. The fig graph is displayed on the dashboard.
BUT!

When I add a new `fluidRow` the fig graph disappears. For example let me provide you with a `body` part of code:

```
 body <- dashboardBody(
fluidRow(
    box(widht = 12, title = 'Group', textOutput('group_name'))
),
fluidRow(
    box(width = 4, title = 'Firm', textOutput('firm_name')),
    box(width = 4, title = 'INN', textOutput('firm_inn')),
    box(width = 4, title = 'Branch', textOutput('firm_branch'))
),
fluidRow(
    box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name1', plotlyOutput('firm_limits_utiliz'), solidHeader = TRUE),
    box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name2', plotlyOutput('firm_limits_remains'), solidHeader = TRUE),
    box(status = 'warning', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name3',  tableOutput('group_limits') , solidHeader = TRUE,
        style = "overflow-x: scroll;")
),
# Here i a new fluidRow
fluidRow(
        box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name6', plotlyOutput('group_limit_utiliz'), solidHeader = TRUE),
        box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name4', plotlyOutput('gtoup_limit_remains'), solidHeader = TRUE),
        box(status = 'warning', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name5',  tableOutput('group_limits') , solidHeader = TRUE,
            style = "overflow-x: scroll;")
        
    )
 )
```

As you may see there is a new `fluidRow`. In this case the `fig` with `firm_limits_utiliz` id graph disappears.
What's the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you create a copy of output with another variable name:

```
#new fluidRow

  fluidRow(
    box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name6', plotlyOutput('group_limit_utiliz2'), solidHeader = TRUE),
    box(status = 'primary', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name4', plotlyOutput('gtoup_limit_remains2'), solidHeader = TRUE),
    box(status = 'warning', height = '250px', width = 4, title = 'name5',  tableOutput('group_limits2') , solidHeader = TRUE,
        style = "overflow-x: scroll;")

  )
```

Output:

```
  output$group_limit_utiliz2 <- renderPlotly({
    fig2 <- plot_ly(
      domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
      value = 270,
      # title = list(text = "Speed"),
      type = "indicator",
      mode = "gauge+number",
      height = 197, width = 393) 
    fig2 <- fig2 %>%
      layout(margin = list(l=20,r=30))
    
    fig2
  })
```

Note that I added a **2** to all variable names, but everything else is the same.

[image]